# Transforming absolute derivative of separation four-vectors in GR

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

Moore (*A General Relativity Workbook)* claims that the following implication holds, where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the separation four-vector between two objects at a given proper time:

$$
\frac{d\boldsymbol{n}}{d\tau} =\Big(\frac{dn^\alpha}{d\tau}+\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\sigma\mu}n^\sigma u^\mu\Big)\boldsymbol{e}_\alpha \implies \Big(\frac{d\boldsymbol{n}}{d\tau}\Big)^\alpha =\frac{dn^\alpha}{d\tau}+\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\sigma\mu}n^\sigma u^\mu, \text{where}
$$

the $\Gamma$s are Christoffel symbols.

I, however, cannot see how it is possible to transform a basis vector into an exponent on the LHS.  Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\alpha$ here is not an exponent and does not denote a power. Instead, it denotes the $\alpha$-th component of the vector in the brackets, since vector components have upper indices by convention. The step you quote is simply taking the component of a vector. There is no "transformation" taking place here at all.

As you know, a vector is written in Einstein notation as
$$\mathbf{v} = v^\mu \mathbf{e}_\mu$$
and if you have a complicated expression such as (just a random example)
$$\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v} + g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\mathbf{w} -\mathbf{w}$$
then its $\mu$-th component is written as
$$u^\mu = \left(\mathbf{v} + g(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\mathbf{w} -\mathbf{w}\right)^\mu \\ = v^\mu + \left(g_{\rho\lambda} v^\rho w^\lambda\right) w^\mu - w^\mu$$

Comment: Of course, I got confused by the wording of the question.  Thanks.